# rails 3.2 collection_select not loading values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue using collection_select to create a drop down menu.  all the guides say that this

```
<%= collection_select(:page, :user_id, @users, :id, :full_name) %>
```

should work but when I run the server, instead of a list of users appearing it's just a blank list.  The associations are that page belongs a user and a user has many pages, and there are users in the database that should be obtained in the controller when I call @users = User.all

Any idea on how to get the drop down list to populate?

Comment: Is user has `field full_name` or method has `full_name` ? & is it a standard `form_for` syntax?

Comment: it's inside a form_for so I can submit it with the other information but it is not using that form_for so I can assign it to a different model instead.  the user has the field full_name because of the method in the model that combines the first name and last name using "#{first_name} #{last_name}"

Comment: Your code seems to be correct `<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :full_name) %>` try this if it's in page model,

Comment: I created a new form_for for a page model and added the f.collection_select in and it was still blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you load anything into the `@users` variable in your `PageController` ?

If it does not belong (semantically) to the controller, make it a helper method

```
module PagesHelper
  def users_for_select
    User.all
  end
end
```

and in the view

```
<%= collection_select(:page, :user_id, users_for_select, :id, :full_name) %>
```

Check also in the console that `:full_name` is a proper method of a User instance

```
User.first.full_name
```

Edit: proposal for a `full_name` method with fallback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}".presence or name
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, I used @users = User.all in my controller, I tried using the helper method you wrote however the same issue occurred and no values are being generated.

Comment: Can you post the content of the `full_name` method for the User class?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use the console to test it, however I did add <%= User.first.full_name %> into the view and nothing appeared, however it also did not throw any errors.

Comment: Please post the contents of the :full_name method. (in a pastebin if needed)

Comment: @Kevin
check my comment down once and let me know what you see when you give :first_name instead of :full_name

Comment: @user1455116 that is probably the point. The :full_name method is giving empty results, so the need to see it.

Comment: def full_name
        "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end

that is the method and it lives in the user model, what is weird however is that the comment on the other answer showed that :name and :id worked and did display correctly, however :first_name did not but it is a column in the users table as well

Comment: Change the full_name to have a fallback to name: `def full_name; "#{first_name} #{last_name}".presence or name; end`. This will use the name in case neither the first nor the last name is set.

Comment: this worked great thanks, the issue I was having was I forgot that none of the first or last names were set.

Answer (score 1):

i too went through the apidocuments,

somewhere it says that no selection is made without including :prompt or :include_blank if your calling method is nil,

try `<%= collection_select(:page, :user_id, @users, :id, :full_name, :prompt=>true) %>`

Comment: I tried adding prompt=>true however nothing happened as well, this is the html code that is generated from the code.

    <select id="page_user_id" name="page[user_id]"><option value="1"> </option>
<option value="2"> </option>
<option value="3"> </option>
<option value="4" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="5"> </option>
<option value="6"> </option>
<option value="7"> </option></select> '

Comment: I did and it displayed 7 users, I used @users though as .all threw a method doesn't exist error.

Comment: @Kevin  oh the value is coming the text_method is not working and so you cannot see the full_name. Something must be wrong with full_name, try printing @users.full_name once and see what it prints `<%= @users.full_name%>`

Comment: thanks I have a good idea on what the issue is now, it's because @users is a list of users and the full_name method can only be applied to a single user, which is why it's throwing an error if I try @ users.full_name, or @ users.first_name.  from what I've read however I thought it should be able to process each user individually from the @ users list.

Also I had to put a space between the @ and user because otherwise it wouldn't let me post as apparently it notifies a previous commenter.

Comment: do you have any solution on how to potentially fix this issue however?  I tried using @user.find(1) instead of @users and it gave me a map error, so I'm assuming the parameter should be a list instead of a single user

Comment: @Kevin
what you thought is correct about collection select, if you give it a collection, it will display one by one in thr drop down and it is doing that already, which is why you are able to see 7 id's form the `@users` collection. just to check once again, you can replace :full_name in the collection select with :first_name, or :id again, if you change to id you will see 1 to 7 in the drop down, and :first_name will show you the seven first names please check and let me know if you are able to see

Comment: thanks, for some reason id did work, however :first_name did not, I did get :name to work though which is weird because all 3 of those are columns that exist in the users table.